# XUnit Class Fixture (IClassFixture) is being executed twice

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xunit, xunit.net, xunit2

**TextFixture and Test**

```
public class TestFixture : IDisposable
{
    public TestFixture()
    {
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", true);
        WebDriver.Init("https://localhost:44335/", Browser.Chrome, options);
        WebDriver.GetDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        WebDriver.Close();
    }
}

public abstract class Test : IClassFixture<TestFixture>
{

}
```

**AuthTest**

```
public abstract class AuthTest : Test
{
    [Fact, Priority(-1)]
    public void LoginTest()
    {
        var home = GetPage<HomePage>();
        home.LoginModal.Open();
        home.LoginModal.EnterLoginText(new Login("user", "pw"));
        home.LoginModal.Login();
        GetPage<DashboardPage>().IsAt();
    }
}
```

**HomeTest**

```
[TestCaseOrderer(PriorityOrderer.Name, PriorityOrderer.Assembly)]
public sealed class HomeTest : AuthTest
{

}
```

**ProfileTest**

```
 [TestCaseOrderer(PriorityOrderer.Name, PriorityOrderer.Assembly)]
 public sealed class ProfileTest : AuthTest
 {
     [Fact, Priority(0)]
     public void OpenProfilePageTest()
     {
         var profile = GetPage<ProfilePage>();
         profile.GoTo();
         profile.IsAt();
     }
     [Fact, Priority(1)]
     public void LogoutTest() => GetPage<DashboardPage>().Logout();

 }
```

A few days ago I wrote this code and it used to create 1 browser instance. I started the project today again and now suddenly the fixture gets executed twice and it opens two seperate browsers (which causes my tests to fail). I thought the `IClassFixture` was supposed to only execute once like `[OneTimeSetUp]` attribute in NUnit. Why is my fixture executing twice?

This happens when I run all tests (all tests runs`ProfileTest` and `HomeTest`). If I run for example one of the two tests individually, then just 1 browser instance opens and the test passes.

I'm using XUnit 2.4.0.

**- EDIT -**

When I use:

VS 2019 (run all tests): It opens 2 browsers at same time and fails.

VS 2019 (debug all tests): It opens 2 browsers at same time and fails.

Jetbrain's Rider IDE (run all tests): It opens 2 browsers at same time and fails.

Jetbrain's Rider IDE (debug all tests): It opens 1 browser till `HomeTest` finishes and then another browser for `ProfileTest`, and both tests pass (including `LoginTest`).

This last is how it is supposed to work and it used to be like this when I used NUnit before.

Comment: I don't think it's because of xUnit, It's a selenium problem.

Comment: But if I change the code to make use of NUnit `[OneTimeSetUp]` rather than XUnit it does what I want.

Comment: After a close look I think your `TestFixture` method being recognised as a test too. Decorate it with a `Fact[(skip="some reason")]` attribute.

Comment: Rider test executor will run tests one by one if debugger attached, in other cases different classes tests will be executed in parallel by default

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#class-fixture

> You can use the class fixture feature of xUnit.net to share a single
>   object instance **among all tests in a test class**

Notice *in a test class*

In you case you have two separated classes `HomeTest` and `ProfileTest`, regardless of both are derived from same abstracted class, they are treated by xUnit as two different test classes.

Consider to use `Collection Fixtures` instead.
https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#collection-fixture

> You can use the collection fixture feature of xUnit.net to share a
>   single object instance **among tests in several test class**